# How to submit a form information to another div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please 2 divs are placed side by side, a form is created in the one on the left hand, when the form is filled and submitted the information appears on div on the right hand a line is role, the form is reset, filled and submitted again...

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: use ajax and fill the second div in with the callback

Comment: Vote close too broad

Answer (score 0):

Here something

```
<div id="d1">
<form>
<input id="myTx" type="text">
</form>
</div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

function for passing values to div 2

```
$("#myTx").change(function(){

  var bla = $("#myTx").val();
    $("#d2").html(bla);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If u want to copy form data to another div then page should not refresh on submit. So u need to use Ajax to submit form without refresh then u can use Javascript to copy data to another div.